# Embed information in jpeg image from Android and send it to ASP.NET web application

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net

I am currently able to receive a base64 string from an Android app at my ASP.NET web app which I am able to convert back to a jpeg image to be displayed.

However, the current base64 string only contains information about the pixel distribution of the image.

What if I want to embed more information in the base64 string such as date picture was taken, name of image etc. and then send it to the web app.

At the web application, I would like to read these string and create folders according to date image was created automatically and sort those images into the folder on a local drive.

How do I achieve all this?